# Issue with printing an arbitrary sequence of strings and images in C#

Tags: c#, printing

So, long story short: I'm writing a POS program, and I have a receipt printer connected and the Windows Forms printing API works great with it, much easier than I expected.

However, searching through the API, it seems that the easiest (or perhaps only) way to programmatically print something is to use the `Graphics` object inside the `PrintPageEventArgs` object in the printer's event handling method.

Every overloaded parameter list for the `Graphics.DrawXXX()` method requires some kind of coordinate pair to use as a reference point for where to start drawing the object passed to it.

So my question is, let's say I want to print some `string` value, and then an `Image.` Doing it the other way around (first the `Image,` then the `string`) would be easy because the reference point to start drawing the `string` would be `(0, Image.Size.Height).` However, since a `string` does not have a "size" associated with it, what is the best way to go about telling the printer where to start drawing an image after a string has been printed?

Let me know if this is confusing or needs additional clarification.

Comment: It is somewhat surprising that string's size can't be measured with [MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)... or I'm missing something in "string does not have a "size" associated with it"?

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea that method even existed in Graphics.... looks to be just the thing I'm looking for.